# React Native no ask me for permission dialogue

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-permissions

I'm trying to get the location of my user on android using React Native. I have added the location privacy description in the plist, and I have tried various codes but none show the dialogue asking permission. Right now, I'm using this library: https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions

this is my code but it doesnt ask me for permissions or when i open it manually, its not show me user marker

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions';

export default class CurrentPosition extends Component {
    state = {
        region: {
      latitude: 36.726215,
      longitude: 27.685844,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0090,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0095,
        },
    };

omponentDidMount() {
        Permissions.request('location').then(response => {
           console.log(response)
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    loadingEnabled={true}
                   showsUserLocation={true}
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={this.state.region}
                >
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Permissions is not being called because "omponentDidMount" has to be renamed to "componentDidMount"?

Comment: Sorry I tried that way too, i forgot this bu i changed this and not working again, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Which version of react-native-permissions do you use? Your code seems like you are using v1.x.x.
Check https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#migrating-from-v1xx

Comment: @schogges bro thank you very very very very much, its working now, i didnt see this, thank you again.